# Controller not getting $http return data from factory in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, factory

Been trying to get this code to return http return data in $scope.top and use that data on the page to populate an element using {{top}}.

All variations I've tried either result in an empty $scope.top or $scope.top data arriving too late to be used on the page.

Latest attempt:

```
var app = angular.module("it", []);
    app.factory('dataProvider', function($http){
        return {
            getTop: function(){
                return $http.get("db.php");
            }
        }
    });

    app.controller('topList', function($log, $scope, dataProvider){
        $scope.getTop = function(){
            var promise = dataProvider.getTop();
            promise.then(
                function(data){ 
                    $scope.top = data.data;
                },
                function(errorData){
                    $log.error('failure loading', errorData);
                });
        }

    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `$http` promise resolves with a `response` object, not the response body / data. You want `$scope.top = data.data`. Voting to close as a *typo*

Comment: Mistakenly deleted  `data.data` when preparing question. It's still not working. Does it look like it should work otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean by *"data arriving too late to be used on the page"*? Sounds like it's working if the data arrives (eventually).

Comment: I tried another setup where the `getTop` function included `.then` statements but the controller never received the data in time.

With this setup `$scope.top` gives me nothing.

Comment: Again, what does *"never received the data **in time**"* mean? There does not appear to be anything wrong with your code. The issue appears to be with your expectation of **when** something should happen.

Comment: `$scope.top` is required when the page loads for `<span ng-repeat="t in top" >{{t}}</span>`. I'm surprised there is nothing wrong with the code...`console.log($scope.top)` returns nothing.

Comment: Again, there is nothing wrong with that code. **When** the data is retrieved, your template will show the repeated data. If you want to show something else before the data loads, you'll need to engineer that yourself.

Comment: Just realized, I forgot to run `$scope.getTop();` sigh... thanks for verifying rest of code is fine.